# Chrome device mode shows background color where there is none

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My site works fine in all major browsers including Chrome desktop and mobile. Now I noticed that when entering the device mode in Chrome devtools (Chrome 46) a portion of the page that has no background color set appears in dark grey. When inspecting the elements in this area none has a background color set.

[image]

As I have mentioned earlier, this does not happen in Chrome on mobile or any other browser.

The site is [here](http://formfunk-podcast.de). It only happens when first loading the page. (After clicking around on the site the body element has a white background color set and the glitch is not happening anymore.)

Any ideas what causes this?

**Update:** Gabee points out below:

> Unable to reproduce on the latest Canary with the new Device Mode (but I can on the stable), so (...) [y]ou just need to wait for the next update (or two?) for the fix to land

I consider this solved, then.

Comment: Did you try viewing the site in your mobile device? Chrome fills up space with dark grey sometimes if the elements don't cover viewport (unlike desktop preview where absence of content gives a white color) .

Comment: The error is not happening on my mobile device, only in Chrome devtools. Also, the html and body elements do cover the viewport as far as I can tell by inspecting them in devtools.

Comment: Might be an accidental bleed-through of the dark-grey grid. Unable to reproduce on the latest Canary with the new Device Mode (but I can on the stable), so sorry but looks like something that won't get fixed in a stable patch. You just need to wait for the next update (or two?) for the fix to land.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if it's a bleed-through. At least the gray values differ. Should I file a bug somewhere or is this redundant since it's apparently not a problem in Canary?

Comment: It will be redundant since it is working in Canary, and closed as fixed. New versions of Chrome aren't pushed for DevTools issues. So all that can be done is wait for a version with the fix to be released since it is already clearly fixed in Canary.

Comment: Is this back again?  I'm on 53.0.2785.116.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gabee points out:

> Unable to reproduce on the latest Canary with the new Device Mode (but I can on the stable), so (...) [y]ou just need to wait for the next update (or two?) for the fix to land

I consider this solved.